# UWP re-use visual state manager

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, responsive, visualstatemanager

Why don't we have such easy responsive helpers for UWP?

I have these styles in a separate .xaml file:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Project.App.WindowsApp.Styles">
    <Style x:Key="TextTitleH1" TargetType="TextBlock" >
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Quicksand"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TextTitleH2" TargetType="TextBlock" >
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Quicksand"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TextTitleH3" TargetType="TextBlock" >
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Quicksand"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TextTitleH4" TargetType="TextBlock" >
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Quicksand"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TextNormal" TargetType="TextBlock" >
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Quicksand"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have a page using these styles (leaving out a lot of code for simplicity):

```
<ScrollViewer >
    <Grid>
       ...

        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Source={CustomResource Page_Dashboard_LatestImage}}" Style="{StaticResource TextTitleH4}" />
            ...
            <TextBlock Text="{CustomResource Page_Dashboard_NoImage}" Style="{StaticResource TextNormal}"/>

            <TextBlock Text="{CustomResource Page_Dashboard_LatestImage_Description}" Style="{StaticResource TextNormal}" />
         ...

        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={CustomResource Page_Dashboard_TipsTitle}} Style="{StaticResource TextTitleH4}" />
            ...
        </StackPanel>
     ...
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Now I could give all of those controls a `x:Name` and use `VisualStateManager` within this page to resize the text, but I am using these text styles throughout the entire app and I want to change them at one point, defining a fontsize for different screen sizes, using a simple css-like query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .TextTileH1 {
    font-size: 36;
  }
}
```

So how can I generically use `VisualStateManager` within a `ResourceDirectory` to change all text styles at once for a different screen size?

I have tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31916771/2901207), but as per my comment I was not able to succeed, I've tried to apply a bigger margin to one of the `<StackPanel>`'s (also giving it a name like it should) but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

After testing what you provided ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912603/how-do-i-reuse-visualstate-visualstategroup-and-vsualstatemanager-in-shared-res/31916771#31916771)), I modified some code:

```cs
public class VisualStateExtensions : DependencyObject
{
    public static void SetVisualStatefromTemplate(UIElement element, DataTemplate value)
    {
        element.SetValue(VisualStatefromTemplateProperty, value);
    }

    public static DataTemplate GetVisualStatefromTemplate(UIElement element)
    {
        return (DataTemplate)element.GetValue(VisualStatefromTemplateProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualStatefromTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("VisualStatefromTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(VisualStateExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(null,new PropertyChangedCallback(VisualStatefromTemplateChanged)));

    private static void VisualStatefromTemplateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
        {
            var visualStateGroups = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(frameworkElement);
            if (visualStateGroups != null)
            {
                var template = (DataTemplate)e.NewValue;
                var content = (FrameworkElement)template.LoadContent();
                var groups = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(content);
                if (groups!=null && groups.Count>0)
                {
                    var original = groups.First();
                    groups.Remove(original);
                    visualStateGroups.Add(original);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

App.xaml

```xml
...
<DataTemplate x:Key="VisualStateTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup >
                <VisualState x:Name="NarrowView" >
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="Header.FontSize" Value="20" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="WideView">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1000" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="Header.FontSize" Value="30" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
...
```

MainPage.xaml

```xml
<Grid controls:VisualStateExtensions.VisualStatefromTemplate="{StaticResource VisualStateTemplate}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="Header" Text="Hello World!"/>
</Grid>
```

Best regards.

Comment: thanks for those modifications, noticed that one of the `if` conditions wasn't true as well. But unfortunately it does not change the text font size, I think I am missing something but for testing purposes I'have done the same thing. is `controls:` referring to the namespace of `VisualStateExtensions`? Does it matter if it is on the `Grid` or (in my case) on the `ScrollViewer`? To make sure I have checked that the `VisualStateManager` itself was working when pasted inside the `ScrollViewer` (outside the `Grid`).

Comment: Yes, `controls:` is the namespace reference. I suggest putting this `VisualStateExtensions.VisualStatefromTemplate` on the root element. For example, if your `Grid` is in `ScrollViewer`, then write this extension on `ScrollViewer`

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't seem to change anything related to the font. Have you tested your code in a test project?

Comment: Yes, I tested it and it worked fine. Does your content in the `Grid` correspond to the content in the `VisualStateGroup`? For example, in the `VisualStateGroup`, I set a `VisualState` Target to `Header.FontSize`, and at the same time, there must be a `TextBlock` with the actual name `Header`. If your code still does not work, please post the complete code for our analysis.

Comment: Ah it works now! Although it is not the best solution as I need to add a `x:Name` everywhere, it is a bit easier by just adding a lot of `x:Name="TextTitleH1_1"`, `x:Name="TextTitleH1_2"`, etc. and just have those in the datatemplate as well. So until someone finds a better solution, I will mark this as accepted...

Comment: Hmm.. I see what issue I had: When I include `Setter`s to Targets that do not exist, then all the setters won't be triggered. Which means I cannot do what I intent to do in my last comment, which means it cannot really be re-used across multiple pages... back to being stuck again haha...

Comment: XAML and HTML are different after all. XAML is a strict type correspondence, and controls are found by name. This is quite different from the CSS class. If you need to reuse, you can consider using `UserControl` to integrate some control components, and then reuse this usercontrol.